# Configurar dns Bind9 Debian

Tags: dns, linux

Tenho uma rede que está configurada assim:

```
Endereço IP:    138.94.189.185  PPPoE
Máscara de Sub-rede:    255.255.255.0    
Gateway:    138.94.189.185   
Servidor DNS:   138.94.188.19 , 8.8.8.8
```

Estou querendo fazer meu servidor Debian um servidor de Hospedagem. E para o Registro.br achar meus Dns preciso instalar o [Bind9](https://wiki.debian.org/Bind9), só que não estou conseguindo.

Quando executo o comando:

```
host -l site.local
```

Tenho o retorno:

> Host site.local not found: 2(SERVFAIL) ; Transfer failed.

Estou fazendo dessa forma:

**`/etc/bind/named.conf.options`**

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

         forwarders {
                138.94.189.185;
                8.8.8.8;
         };

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
```

**`/etc/bind/named.conf.local`**

```
// Zona de pesquisa direta
 zone "site.local" {
 type master;
 file "/etc/bind/db.labdns.site.local";
 };
// Zona de pesquisa reversa
 zone "189.94.138.in-addr.arpa" {
 type master;
 file "/etc/bind/db.192";
 };
```

**`/etc/bind/db.labdns.site.local`**

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     webserver.site.local. root.site.local. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      webserver.site.local.
@       IN      A       138.94.189.185
@       IN      AAAA    ::1
webserver IN    A       138.94.189.185
roteador IN     A       10.0.0.1
www     IN      CNAME   site.local.
```

**`/etc/bind/db.192`**

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     webserver.site.local. root.site.local. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      webserver.
1       IN      PTR     roteador.site.local.
185 IN          PTR     webserver.site.local.
```

Comment: Por que fechar?

Comment: Eu tirei desse tutorial http://www.cleuber.com.br/index.php/2014/10/01/criando-um-servidor-de-dns-no-ubuntu-14-04 onde estou errando?

Comment: Peri to vendo aqui....

Comment: valeu MagicHat!

Comment: como está o arquivo `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: entra aqui e me chama... https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59922/room-name

Comment: search           site.local
nameserver 138.94.189.185
nameserver 138.94.188.19
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 208.67.220.220

Comment: entra no link que mandei...

Comment: Cara vc sabe pq quando digita o dominio com o www vai para a pagina do Apache e quando digito o dominio sem o www vai para o site corretamente?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/94014/domain-without-the-www-gives-me-the-apache-it-works-page veja isto

Comment: consegui amigo, outra pergunta seria com relação ao mapa do google que nao aparece, já gerei uma chave api para o dominio e nao funcionou sabe me dizer o que pode ser?

Comment: pega o código que estar a tentar e abre uma questão, antes dê uma pesquisada no próprio SOpt, vejo mto essse tipo de questão, tô mei enrolado hj... e chama eu lá no chat principal `@` meu nick...

Comment: @MagicHat Agora eu nao consigo mais entrar nos meus sites, tipo assim, quando digito 138.94.189.185/empresa deveria abrir um site em vez disso abre o dominio que configurei no meu Denian. Teria como acessar meus sites com meu ip, junto com o meu dominio?

Comment: Fiz o seguinte, copiei o site para a pasta do meu dominio e funcionou

Comment: novas questões se pertencerem ao esopo do SOpt devem ser feitas em novos posts, ou lá no chat principal como mencionei.

Comment: Não é necessário reabrir esta questão devido ao erro ser  de digitação.